# В базе Django проблема с SlugField

Tags: django, python-3.x, slug

Создаю модель статьи на django 1.10. Ввожу название статьи на русском в админке.
prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)} отрабатывает нормально, т.е 'Тест' переводится в 'test'.

Но при записи в базу в поле попадают только цифры и латинские символы. Почему так происходит? Хотя если изначально название написать на английском, то все сохраняется в базу нормально. База SQLite.

**models.py**

```
    class Rubric(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)                       
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)                                       

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                           
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)                                         
    super(Rubric,self).save(*args, **kwargs)                               

class Meta:                                                                
    verbose_name_plural = 'Рубрики'                                        

def __str__(self):                                                         
    return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
  from blog.models import Rubric, Article

  class RubricAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}

  admin.site.register(Rubric, RubricAdmin)

  class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}

  admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде не видно откуда вы импортируете slugify. Предполагаю, что это строка в models.py:
*from django.utils.text import slugify*

Если так, то посмотрите документацию по [django.utils.text.slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify)
Там сказано, что по умолчанию используется кодировка ascii. Если вы хотите использовать преобразование из utf-8, то сделайте:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name, allow_unicode=True)
    super(Rubric, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

А если вы используете заполнение формы только в админке, то вообще уберите из модели этот метод save.